# Mousemove within mousedown stops mouse up firing

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mouseevent

I'm capturing the mouse position within a SVG group (`<g>`) while the mouse is held down.

However, the `mousemove` continues firing after the mouse button is released and any attempt to attach a `mouseup` event is ignored.

```
var ternary = d3.select("#ternary");

var pointer;
var selector = ternary.append("g");

selector.on("mousedown", function() {
  console.log('down');

  selector.on("mousemove", function() {
    console.log('move');
    var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
    console.log(mouse[0])
    console.log(mouse[1]);
    // continues firing after mouse button released 
    // how do I clear?
  });

  selector.on("mouseup", function() {

    alert('release');
    //this event doesnt fire
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Two considerations:

1. A `<g>` element, as a container, will take the size of its content, which are the responsible for the mouse events;
2. The `mouseup` does fire, as you can see here (only changing the `<g>` for the `<svg>`):

```js
var selector = d3.select("svg");

selector.on("mousedown", function() {
  console.log('down');

  selector.on("mousemove", function() {
    console.log('move');
    var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
    console.log(mouse[0])
    console.log(mouse[1]);
    // continues firing after mouse button released 
    // how do I clear?
  });

  selector.on("mouseup", function() {

    alert('release');
    //this event doesnt fire
  });
});
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: tan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Therefore, you have just one answerable question here: *"[mousemove] continues firing after mouse button released, how do I clear [it]?"*.

Just pass `null` to the event handler:

```
selector.on("mousemove", null);
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var selector = d3.select("svg");

selector.on("mousedown", function() {
  console.log('down');

  selector.on("mousemove", function() {
    console.log('move');
    var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
    console.log(mouse[0])
    console.log(mouse[1]);
    // continues firing after mouse button released 
    // how do I clear?
  });

  selector.on("mouseup", function() {

    selector.on("mousemove", null);

    alert('release');
    //this event doesnt fire
  });
});
```

```css
svg {
  background-color: tan;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```